# That's right ? $\operatorname{Re}(\sqrt{-z}\delta)>0~$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Helle, everyone. I want to check this question and find it in an article.
[image]
so that 
$$s(r_{0},\theta_{0})~:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}:|z|\geqslant r_{0}~~\text{ et}~~|\arg\left(z\right)\bigr|<\theta_{0}\right\}\cup B(0,r_{0}).$$
$$\displaystyle\Sigma_{r_{0},\theta_{0}}=\mathbb{C} \setminus s(r_{0},\theta_{0})$$
$$S(r_{0},\theta_{0})~:=\left\{t\in\mathbb{C}  \setminus\left\{0\right\}:\left|t\right|\geqslant\sqrt{r_{0}}\ \ \mathrm{et}\ \ |\mathrm{arg}\,t\right|\leq(\pi-\theta_{0})/2\}$$
$$\text{and} \gamma~:=\partial \displaystyle\Sigma_{r_{0},\theta_{0}}$$
$\theta_{0}\in\left ]0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right[~~,~~r_{0}>0$
Violet range is $s(r_{0},\theta_{0})$ The remaining range is $\Sigma_{r_{0},\theta_{0}}$ Which in red is $\gamma~:=\partial \displaystyle\Sigma_{r_{0},\theta_{0}}$

[image]

I didn't understand how this relationship was right?
$\operatorname{Re}(\sqrt{-z}\delta)>0~$et$~~\operatorname{Re} (\sqrt{-z}\left|x\right|)>0$
This last relationship 
$\operatorname{Re} (\sqrt{-z}\delta)=\delta\,\sqrt{|z|}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\theta_{0}}{2}\right)=\delta\,\sqrt{|z|}\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta_{0}}{2}\right)$
is wrong Because it's only an investigator $\operatorname {\Im} z\leq 0$ look the fllowing image\

[image]

i know that $z=|z|e^{i\arg \left( z\right)}~~\Rightarrow~~ \sqrt{-z}=\sqrt{|z|}e^{i\dfrac{\arg \left( -z\right)}{2}}=\sqrt{|z|}e^{i\dfrac{\pi+\arg \left( z\right)}{2}}$.
Am I right ?

---

Thank you.